# MBean of Hornetq is not exposed in WildFly

Tags: jmx, wildfly, hornetq

Although [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html_single/#management.jmx.configuration) it is described that JMX is enabled by default in HornetQ, I do not see any MBeans in jconsole, after connectin to the process of WildFly. What do I miss?

- WildFly 8.2.0.Final
- HornetQ 2.4.5.Final ([here are all component versions in WildFyl 8.2.0.Final](http://wildfly.org/news/2014/11/20/WildFly82-Final-Released/))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After backup-ing, edit your server config XML file (e.g standalone-full.xml) and add the `jmx-management-enabled` XML element, as described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html_single/#management.jmx.configuration) for disabling JMX:

```
    .......
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0">
        <hornetq-server>
             <!-- next line is to be added -->
             <jmx-management-enabled>true</jmx-management-enabled>
             ...........
        </hornetq-server>
    ...........
```

After that restart WildFly.